# python 3 tkinter: how to add .after() to graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i am trying to make a circle that slowly gets bigger and to do so i need to add a delay. I tried using `time.sleep()` but found out that won't work and that i need to use `.after()`. i have tried making a function that makes the circle but that didn't work. i have tried adding a lambda before the oval is created but that didn't work either. is there anyway i can add a delay before the new circle is made?
Thanks.

My code:-

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
c.pack()

oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 1, 1)

for x in range(2, 200, 5):
    c.delete(oval)
    root.after(100, oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, x, x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root.after()` takes a ms delay and a function to run after that delay. What you are trying to do is after that delay run a function with a parameter which is `x` (the radius of the circle). The problem with this is that you cannot ask it to run a function with an input.

To get around this, you could use an update function and then global variables for the radius of the circle etc.

This worked for me:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500, highlightthickness = 0)
c.pack()

oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, 1, 1)
r = 2

def update():
    global r, oval
    if x < 200:
        x += 5
    c.delete(oval)
    oval = c.create_oval(0, 0, r, r)
    root.after(100, update)

update()
root.mainloop()
```

I also added the option highlightthickness = 0 to your canvas because otherwise  the coordinate system does not match up and your circles will overflow out of the canvas.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, it fixed my problem. also what does the root.mainloop() do?

Comment: because tkinter is a GUI, it is different to say a prime calculating program. In a prime calculating program, steps are followed after each other to reach an outcome. Tkinter is an interface so has to always be ready, waiting in a constant loop ( the root.mainloop ) for any user mouse clicks or key presses etc.

Also, as my solution fixed your problem, please mark it as the excepted answer.